# Loop through all buttons on screen for a given tag, WP7, using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm looking for a simple way to loop through all buttons onscreen for a given tag. Eg "foo". I'm using WP7, using C#. I'm very new to the platform so go easy on me :P

Googling this sort of thing isn't really working out for me either - I think I have my terminology wrong, so any tips on that too would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably loop through all the controls on your page, check whether each one is a button, and if so check its Tag property.

Something like this...

```
foreach (UIElement ctrl in ContentPanel.Children)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        Button potentialButton = ((Button)ctrl);
        if (potentialButton.Tag = Tag)
            return (Button)ctrl;
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, though, that if you have nested controls on the page, you will need to think about recursing into any item with children to make sure you catch all the controls.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a method to enumerate recursively the controls in your page:

```
    public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> FindVisualChildren(FrameworkElement control)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control); i++)
        {
            var child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i) as FrameworkElement;


            if (child != null)
            {
                yield return child;

                foreach (var grandChild in FindVisualChildren(child))
                {
                    yield return grandChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call it and keep only the controls you want:

```
        var buttons = FindVisualChildren(this.ContentPanel)
            .OfType<Button>()
            .Where(b => b.Tag is string && (string)b.Tag == "foo");
```

(where ContentPanel is the root element of your page)