# How to interact with variables (just created in the program) that are in another method?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In the first method I'm creating a matrix of textboxes and in another (Button_click) method. **I need to take the values of textboxes** from the Button_Click method and then do something with them. I don't know how interact with just created values(the names are also new). But I know that I can't use `t[j]`.

```
 private void vsematrici_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedIndex = vsematrici.SelectedIndex+2;
        StackPanel[] v = new StackPanel[selectedIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndex; i++)
        {
            v[i] = new StackPanel();
            v[i].Name = "matrixpanel" + i;
            v[i].Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            TextBox[] t = new TextBox[selectedIndex];
            for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndex; j++)
            {
                t[j] = new TextBox();
                t[j].Name = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                t[j].Text = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                v[i].Children.Add(t[j]);

                Thickness m = t[j].Margin;
                m.Left = 1;
                m.Bottom = 1;
                t[j].Margin = m;

                InputScope scope = new InputScope();
                InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();
                name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber;
                scope.Names.Add(name);
                t[j].InputScope = scope;
            }
            mainpanel.Children.Add(v[i]);

        }
        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Найти определитель";
        button1.Click += Button_Click;
        mainpanel.Children.Add(button1);

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // Double sa11v = Convert.ToDouble(t[j].Text);

    }
```

Sorry for my English, I'm from Russia :)

Comment: if you want to use it in another method, you probably chosen wrong scope for the variable. It should be a field in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a member variable that is used outside the event in which you have created TextBox Array-

```
    TextBox[] _t = null;
    private void vsematrici_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedIndex = vsematrici.SelectedIndex + 2;
        StackPanel[] v = new StackPanel[selectedIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndex; i++)
        {
            v[i] = new StackPanel();
            v[i].Name = "matrixpanel" + i;
            v[i].Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            _t = new TextBox[selectedIndex];
            for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndex; j++)
            {
                _t[j] = new TextBox();
                _t[j].Name = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                _t[j].Text = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                v[i].Children.Add(_t[j]);

                Thickness m = t[j].Margin;
                m.Left = 1;
                m.Bottom = 1;
                _t[j].Margin = m;

                InputScope scope = new InputScope();
                InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();
                name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber;
                scope.Names.Add(name);
                _t[j].InputScope = scope;
            }
            mainpanel.Children.Add(v[i]);

        }
        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Найти определитель";
        button1.Click += Button_Click;
        mainpanel.Children.Add(button1);

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_t != null)
        {
            //Do your work here
            // Double sa11v = Convert.ToDouble(t[j].Text);
        }

    }
```

but for a broader aspect, you can use dictionary,

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> _dicTextBoxes;

    private void vsematrici_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int selectedIndex = vsematrici.SelectedIndex + 2;
        StackPanel[] v = new StackPanel[selectedIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndex; i++)
        {
            v[i] = new StackPanel();
            v[i].Name = "matrixpanel" + i;
            v[i].Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            _dicTextBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
            for (int j = 0; j < selectedIndex; j++)
            {
                TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();

                txtBox = new TextBox();
                txtBox.Name = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                txtBox.Text = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);
                v[i].Children.Add(txtBox);

                Thickness m = txtBox.Margin;
                m.Left = 1;
                m.Bottom = 1;
                txtBox.Margin = m;

                InputScope scope = new InputScope();
                InputScopeName name = new InputScopeName();
                name.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber;
                scope.Names.Add(name);
                txtBox.InputScope = scope;

                _dicTextBoxes.Add(txtBox.Name, txtBox);
            }
            mainpanel.Children.Add(v[i]);

        }
        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Найти определитель";
        button1.Click += Button_Click;
        mainpanel.Children.Add(button1);

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dicTextBoxes != null)
        {
            // a23 is the name of textbox, 'a' is prefixe, '2' is the 2nd stackpanel you have added
            // '3' is the 3rd textbox you have added in stackpanel
            if (_dicTextBoxes.ContainsKey("a23"))
            {
                //Do your work here
                Double sa11v = Convert.ToDouble(_dicTextBoxes["a23"].Text);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And how can I get the values (If I enter them) of textboxes in Button_Click?

Comment: The same way you were accessing like **_t[j].Text;** j is your 0 based index.

Comment: But I'm creating this array "selectedIndex" times to make a matrix, so I can't get values from each textbox that I have created.

May be I can somehow get this values, using just created names of each textbox 't[j].Name = "a" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);'  ?

Comment: off course not, but you must have known to which textbox you have to work out with! If you want a broader aspect, you can use Dictionary<string, TextBox> and then you can find the textbox using its name.

Comment: Can you give an example how can I get these values , please?

I'm learning C# only 2 weeks, so far it hard for me to understand...

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `Children` of `mainpanel` and [check each control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092266/loop-through-all-buttons-on-screen-for-a-given-tag-wp7-using-c-sharp) if it is a `TextBox`. Something like:

```
foreach (UIElement ctrl in mainpanel.Children)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox oneOfYourTextBoxes = ((TextBox)ctrl);
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I get the values (If I enter them) of textboxes in Button_Click?

Comment: This `foreach` should be in your Button_Click event. You now can access each `TextBox` and get its value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change an arrays size after you created it. Hence your size is known only at runtime after firing your event you cannot set its size within the declaration.

```
class MyClass 
{
    Textbox[] myTextBoxes;


    private void vsematrici_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        // ...
        myTextBoxes = new TextBoxes[selectedIndex];
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int myIndex = // your selected item here
        if (this.myTextBoxes != null && myIndex < this.myTextBoxes.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.myTextBoxes[myIndex].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
button1.Click += (sender, args) => DoSomethingToTextboxes(_t);
```